# Data Frame row elements counting

Tags: r, dataframe, counting

How do I count the number of `H` and `T` in each row, and add the results as a new column using R?

[image: coin toss]

Comment: Please specify your language/platform. And if you have found a solution by yourself, post it as an answer (and even you can also approve it) but not as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

I found one solution using R.

```
S <-tosstable.df
L<-as.data.frame(cbind(rowSums(S == "H"), rowSums(S == "T")))
library(plyr)
L<-rename(L, c("V1"="H", "V2"="T"))
all.cols <- cbind(S,L)
```